# Angular2 testing materialize modal to be opened

Tags: angular, jasmine, materialize, angular2-testing

currently I'm writing test for Angular, in which I simulate click on the button, which emits materialize modal open event. On my front-end after click modal is opened and I can see in my chrome inspector, that it has additional class `open`.

But when I try to do it in test, nothing happens (class is not addded). I am using `angular2-materialize` package.

I've tried to write `async` test:

```
it('should open the modal after user clicks button', async(() => {
    let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-btn')).nativeElement;
    btn.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let openModal = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal.open'));
        expect(openModal).not.toBeNull();
    });
}));
```

I've tried to declare `let openModal` outside `whenStable()` method, but no luck.

Also I've tried to use `fakeAsync` with `tick()`:

```
it('should open the modal after user clicks button', fakeAsync(() => {
   let btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-btn')).nativeElement;
   btn.click();
   tick(2000);
   fixture.detectChanges();
   let openModal = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal.open'));
   expect(openModal).not.toBeNull();
}));
```